# MYSQL: select the top N candidates

Tags: mysql, sql, count, max, inner-join

I have the following DB scheme for university elections:

[image: db scheme]

for each department, I have the following positions:

**1 CHEF** (which is the `candidate_position` = 1)

& **6 Members** (which is the `candidate_position` = 2)

I want to obtain the winners of the election in each department.

to obtain the winner of CHEF position in "Informatique" department, I did the following query:

```
SELECT doctor.firstname, doctor.lastname, votes

FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) AS votes FROM candidate_votes WHERE candidate_votes.candidate_position = 1 GROUP BY candidate_votes.candidate_id) AS votes, doctor 

INNER JOIN department_candidates ON department_candidates.doctor_id = doctor.id 

INNER JOIN department ON department.id = department_candidates.department_id AND department.name = 'Informatique' 

INNER JOIN candidate_votes ON candidate_votes.candidate_id = doctor.id AND candidate_votes.candidate_position = 1 

GROUP BY candidates_votes.candidate_id
```

please note I didn't use `LIMIT 1` because may be there is a tie (or draw) of votes between multiple candidates

based on the results, I think that my query of selecting the winner of `Chef` position is right, But I want some help to know how to select the first 6 candidates of `Member` position ?

Data set:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `candidate_votes`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `candidate_votes`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `candidate_votes` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `candidate_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `voter_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `candidate_position` tinyint(1) NOT NULL COMMENT '1: chef, 2: member',
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk-candidate_votes-voter_id` (`voter_id`),
  KEY `fk-candidate_votes-candidate_id_idx` (`candidate_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=36 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `candidate_votes`
--

INSERT INTO `candidate_votes` (`id`, `candidate_id`, `voter_id`, `candidate_position`, `date`) VALUES
(24, 2, 1, 1, '2018-05-26'),
(25, 1, 1, 2, '2018-05-26'),
(26, 6, 1, 2, '2018-05-26'),
(27, 5, 1, 2, '2018-05-26'),
(28, 7, 1, 2, '2018-05-26'),
(29, 8, 1, 2, '2018-05-26'),
(30, 9, 1, 2, '2018-05-26'),
(31, 2, 2, 1, '2018-05-16'),
(32, 3, 7, 1, '2018-05-22'),
(33, 3, 8, 1, '2018-05-22'),
(34, 4, 6, 2, '2018-05-29'),
(35, 7, 6, 2, '2018-05-29');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `department`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `department`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `department` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `department-name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `department`
--

INSERT INTO `department` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'Informatique'),
(2, 'Mathematique'),
(4, 'physique');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `department_candidates`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `department_candidates`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `department_candidates` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `department_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `doctor_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `candidate_position` tinyint(1) NOT NULL COMMENT '1: chef, 2: member',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=15 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `department_candidates`
--

INSERT INTO `department_candidates` (`id`, `department_id`, `doctor_id`, `candidate_position`) VALUES
(5, 1, 3, 1),
(7, 1, 4, 2),
(8, 1, 1, 2),
(9, 1, 2, 1),
(10, 1, 6, 2),
(11, 1, 5, 2),
(12, 1, 7, 2),
(13, 1, 8, 2),
(14, 1, 9, 2);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `doctor`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `doctor`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `doctor` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `firstname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `department_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `doctor`
--

INSERT INTO `doctor` (`id`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `department_id`) VALUES
(1, 'doc1_fn', 'doc1_ln', 1),
(2, 'doc2_fn', 'doc2_ln', 1),
(3, 'doc3_fn', 'doc3_ln', 1),
(4, 'doc4_fn', 'doc4_ln', 1),
(5, 'doc5_fn', 'doc5_ln', 1),
(6, 'doc6_fn', 'doc6_ln', 1),
(7, 'doc7_fn', 'doc7_ln', 1),
(8, 'doc8_fn', 'doc8_ln', 1),
(9, 'doc9_fn', 'doc9_ln', 1);

-- --------------------------------------------------------
```

[Sqlfiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2bd7d8/3)

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Strawberry please check the added example

Comment: Please refer to my previous comment

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem? If not, could you give more information to help solve it?

Comment: @Strawberry please check the sqlfiddle demo

Comment: 'we have a tie between three candidates for the last place' - but why do we care about that?

Comment: also, they all seem to belong to the same department

Comment: @Strawberry I've removed the example, so the fiddle is the only reference. in case of a tie, I want to show all the possible candidates instead of selecting the top N candidates in order and neglect the others.

Comment: But you said that you're only interested in the winners!?!

Comment: @Strawberry I mean that the winner should be determined by the number of votes that he earned regardless of any other factor, so we should take into consideration the tied cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following:

```
SELECT x.*
     , CASE WHEN @prev_position = candidate_position THEN CASE WHEN @prev_total = total THEN @i:=@i ELSE @i:=@i+1 END ELSE @i:=1 END i
     , @prev_position := candidate_position prev_position
     , @prev_total := total prev_total
  FROM
     (
SELECT candidate_id
     , candidate_position
     , COUNT(*) total 
  FROM candidate_votes  
 GROUP 
    BY candidate_id
     , candidate_position
     ) x
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT @prev_position := null,@prev_total:=null,@i:=0) vars
 ORDER
    BY candidate_position
     , total DESC;

+--------------+--------------------+-------+------+---------------+------------+
| candidate_id | candidate_position | total | i    | prev_position | prev_total |
+--------------+--------------------+-------+------+---------------+------------+
|            2 |                  1 |     2 |    1 |             1 |          2 |
|            3 |                  1 |     2 |    1 |             1 |          2 |

|            7 |                  2 |     2 |    1 |             2 |          2 |

|            8 |                  2 |     1 |    2 |             2 |          1 |
|            9 |                  2 |     1 |    2 |             2 |          1 |
|            1 |                  2 |     1 |    2 |             2 |          1 |
|            4 |                  2 |     1 |    2 |             2 |          1 |
|            5 |                  2 |     1 |    2 |             2 |          1 |
|            6 |                  2 |     1 |    2 |             2 |          1 |
+--------------+--------------------+-------+------+---------------+------------+
```

In this example, `i` represents rank. For position 1, we can see that two candidates tied for first place. For position 2, there was one outright winner, with all remaining candidates tying for second place.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently I was trying to be too clever in my other answer, you can achieve a simple ranking table like this:

```
SELECT cast(dc.candidate_position AS UNSIGNED) AS position, dc.doctor_id, doc.firstname, doc.lastname, v.votes
FROM department_candidates dc
JOIN department dept ON dept.id=dc.department_id AND dept.name='Informatique'
JOIN doctor doc ON doc.id=dc.doctor_id
JOIN (SELECT candidate_position AS cp, candidate_id AS cid, count(candidate_id) AS votes
      FROM candidate_votes
      GROUP BY cid) v
  ON v.cid=doc.id AND v.cp = dc.candidate_position
ORDER BY position, v.votes DESC
```

Output:

```
position    doctor_id   firstname   lastname    votes
1           3           doc3_fn     doc3_ln     2
1           2           doc2_fn     doc2_ln     2

2           7           doc7_fn     doc7_ln     2
2           4           doc4_fn     doc4_ln     1
2           1           doc1_fn     doc1_ln     1
2           6           doc6_fn     doc6_ln     1
2           5           doc5_fn     doc5_ln     1
2           8           doc8_fn     doc8_ln     1
2           9           doc9_fn     doc9_ln     1
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2bd7d8/26)

Answer (score 0):

This query will give you the number of votes required to be a winner for a given position (note I have parameterised it with variables):

```
SET @position = 2;
SET @numwinners = 3;
SELECT @rank := @rank+1 AS rank, votes
FROM (SELECT COUNT(candidate_id) AS votes 
      FROM candidate_votes 
      WHERE candidate_position = @position
      GROUP BY candidate_id
      ORDER BY votes DESC) vr
JOIN (select @rank := 0) r
GROUP BY rank
HAVING rank = @numwinners
```

Output for your data with `@position=2` and `@numwinners=3`:

```
rank    votes
3       1
```

Having figured out how many votes are required to be a winner, we just need to find all candidates that have the required number of votes. Since the results are based on number of votes, ties are automatically taken care of. This query will generate that output:

```
SET @position = 2;
SET @numwinners = 3;
SELECT doc.firstname, doc.lastname, v.votes
FROM department_candidates dc
JOIN department dept ON dept.id=dc.department_id AND dept.name='Informatique'
JOIN doctor doc ON doc.id=dc.doctor_id
JOIN (SELECT candidate_id AS cid, count(candidate_id) AS votes
      FROM candidate_votes
      WHERE candidate_position = @position
      GROUP BY cid) v
  ON v.cid=dc.id
WHERE v.votes >= (SELECT votes
                  FROM (SELECT @rank := @rank+1 AS rank, votes
                        FROM (SELECT COUNT(candidate_id) AS votes 
                              FROM candidate_votes 
                              WHERE candidate_position = @position
                              GROUP BY candidate_id
                              ORDER BY votes DESC) vr
                        JOIN (select @rank := 0) r
                        GROUP BY rank
                        HAVING rank = @numwinners
                       ) vt
                  )
ORDER BY v.votes DESC
```

Output for your data with `@position=2` and `@numwinners=3`:

```
firstname   lastname    votes
doc7_fn     doc7_ln     2
doc4_fn     doc4_ln     1
doc1_fn     doc1_ln     1
doc6_fn     doc6_ln     1
doc5_fn     doc5_ln     1
doc8_fn     doc8_ln     1
doc9_fn     doc9_ln     1
```

Output for your data with `@position=1` and `@numwinners=1`:

```
firstname   lastname    votes
doc3_fn     doc3_ln     2
doc2_fn     doc2_ln     2
```

If you want to ensure the query works even if the value of `@numwinners` is greater than the number of candidates, change:

```
HAVING rank = @numwinners
```

to

```
HAVING rank = LEAST(@numwinners, (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT candidate_id)
                                  FROM candidate_votes
                                  WHERE candidate_position = @position))
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2bd7d8/4)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your explanation, your answer is good but I think it doesn't take into consideration to filter by the candidate position, so i think we should add another condition at the end `AND dc.candidate_position = @position`, do you agree?

Comment: It does take that into account  there are two `WHERES` which use candidate_position. try setting @position=1 and then executing the query.

Comment: for `@position = 1` I got no results

Comment: That is odd... look at this [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4b4451/34) it has `@position=1` and `@numwinners=1` and gives 2 results, `doctor_1` and `doctor_2`. Perhaps you left `@numwinners` at a value greater than the number of candidates? it does give no results in that case.

Comment: Hi @Mohammad I've modified the query so that it will work even if `@numwinners` is greater than the number of candidates. I've updated the demo link in the answer too. As far as I can see it works with all combinations of `@position` and `@numwinners`.

Comment: hi, I just added a sqlfiddle demo, please check

Comment: Hi @Mohammad It seems I had a couple of problems. First I misinterpreted `candidate_id` in `candidate_votes`. Second my query only worked because of the particular ordering of the data in the fiddle I set up. Sorry for wasting your time. I think you'll find my edited answer works properly.

Comment: thank you, I really appreciate your effort, but the result is still not as expected, especially for `@position = 1`, it's not giving a result for this position at all

Comment: Hi @Mohammad I don't understand your comment. Did you look at the new link in the edited answer? It uses your data and shows two winners for position 1.